# Two identical HTML documents but one isn't showing style rules?

Tags: html, css, iis, stylesheet

I'm using IIS to test PHP scripts for a small blog project I'm working on. I created the HTML and CSS before setting up the server, but I've run into a problem that makes no sense.

When changing the style rules in my CSS files, the rules will apply to the HTML file when it is opened by clicking on it directly from the folder, but **not** when navigating to it through the localhost IIS link. When accessing it through the local server, CSS rules are not applied, but it's exactly the same single HTML file that should be affected, and in one case it is and the other it isn't.

Why is this happening? Is it just some quirk of IIS or something? I've also noticed new rules don't affect pages on the server unless they are explicitly embedded in the  tag in the HTML file, but this doesn't make sense because they already have style rules from external files applied to them, they're just ignoring new rules.

EDIT: I tried copying everything into a new folder and loading it from the server that way, and the new CSS rules now apply, so it looks like IIS is loading an old version of either the HTML or CSS file.

Comment: Sorry, I've also had this problem with PHP files of the same HTML files. Can I remove tags through editing the post?

Comment: I've updated the post for you. I think you can modify tags though with the `edit` option under them.

Comment: Sounds like the age old caching problem. Have you tried cleared your browser's cache and reloading?

Comment: What pool are you using? Also, like @MrLister said, try clearing your browser's cache.